# Validate formset according master's form field value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, formsets, tabular-form

I have a admin master detail, using tabular inline forms.

I have some special validations to accomplish:

1. If "field_type" is "list", validate that at least one item in the formset has been added.
2. But if not (field_type has another value), do not validate.

If "field_type" is "list", then, make visible the formset, otherwise hide it. This is javascript. I also must validate that on the server. I do that on the clean() of ValueItemInlineFormSet. The problem is that is now validating formset always and it should just happen when field_type = "list". How can I get the value of my master field into the formset?

```
class ValueItemInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        """Check that at least one service has been entered."""
        super(ValueItemInlineFormSet, self).clean()
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        if not any(cleaned_data and not cleaned_data.get('DELETE', False) for cleaned_data in self.cleaned_data):
            raise forms.ValidationError('At least one item required.')

class ValueItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ValueItem
    formset = ValueItemInlineFormSet

class MySelect(forms.Select):

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        if option_value is None:
            option_value = ''
        option_value = force_text(option_value)
        data_attrs = self.attrs['data_attrs']
        option_attrs = ''
        if data_attrs and option_value:
            obj = self.choices.queryset.get(id=option_value)
            for attr in data_attrs:
                attr_value = getattr(obj, attr)
                option_attrs += 'data-{}={} '.format(attr, attr_value)
        if option_value in selected_choices:
            selected_html = mark_safe(' selected="selected"')
            if not self.allow_multiple_selected:
                # Only allow for a single selection.
                selected_choices.remove(option_value)
        else:
            selected_html = ''
        return format_html('<option value="{}" {}{}>{}</option>', option_value, option_attrs, selected_html, force_text(option_label))

class RequirementFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=FieldType.objects.all(),
        widget=MySelect(attrs={'data_attrs': ('identifier', 'name')}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.qs = FieldType.objects.all()
        super(RequirementFieldForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = RequirementField
        fields = ['field_type', 'name', 'description', 'identifier', 'mandatory', 'order_nr', 'active']
```